# Gradle build failed - Spring boot project with lombok

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Cannot build Spring-boot project in Gradle. I get the following error (stack):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by:org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appointmentController' defined in file [C:\Users\triin\Desktop\ValiIT\FinalProject\trikad_uus\build\classes\java\main\ee\bcs\valiit\trikad\controller\AppointmentController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appointmentService' defined in file [C:\Users\triin\Desktop\ValiIT\FinalProject\trikad_uus\build\classes\java\main\ee\bcs\valiit\trikad\service\AppointmentService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.data.AppointmentsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appointmentService' defined in file [C:\Users\triin\Desktop\ValiIT\FinalProject\trikad_uus\build\classes\java\main\ee\bcs\valiit\trikad\service\AppointmentService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.data.AppointmentsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.data.AppointmentsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ...
```

The main problem seems to be in the file **AppointmentController** which is as follows:

```
    package ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.controller;

import ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.data.Appointments;
import ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.service.AppointmentService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Date;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/app")
@Slf4j
public class AppointmentController {

    @Autowired
    private AppointmentService appointmentService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    private void add(@RequestParam String event_name, @RequestParam Date time, @RequestParam String description) {
        Appointments app = new Appointments();
        app.setEventname(event_name);
        app.setTime(time);
        app.setDescription(description);
        appointmentService.add(app);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", produces="application/json")
    private void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Appointments app = appointmentService.get(id);
        appointmentService.delete(app);
    }
}
```

The file AppointmentService, that the controller uses is the following:

```
package ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.service;

import ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.data.Appointments;
import ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.data.AppointmentsRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class AppointmentService {

    @Autowired
    private AppointmentsRepository appointmentsRepository;

    public List<Appointments> list() {
        return appointmentsRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Appointments get(Long id) {
        return appointmentsRepository.getOne(id);
    }

    public List<Appointments> findByUserId(Long id) {
        return appointmentsRepository.findByUserId(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(Appointments appointment) {
        appointmentsRepository.delete(appointment);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void add(Appointments appointment) {
        appointmentsRepository.save(appointment);
    }
}
```

And the repository that the service uses is a simple interface:

```
package ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.data;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Transactional
public interface AppointmentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointments, Long> {

    List<Appointments> findByUserId(Long id);

}
```

Configuration is done by ApplicationContext file which (part of it) is the following:

```
<!-- Common. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="ee.bcs.valiit.trikad" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" file-encoding="UTF-8" />
  <jpa:repositories base-package="ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.data" />
```

Application class

```
package ee.bcs.valiit.trikad;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan ({"ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.data", "ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.service","ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.model", "ee.bcs.valiit.trikad.controller"})
public class TrikadApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TrikadApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My build gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
    ext {
        springVersion = '5.0.8.RELEASE'
        springDataVersion = '2.0.9.RELEASE'
        hibernateVersion = '5.3.5.Final'
        hibernateJpaVersion = '1.0.2.Final'
        postgresqlVersion = '9.4.1212'
        jacksonVersion = '2.9.6'
        lombokVersion = '1.18.2'
        slf4jVersion = '1.7.25'
        junitVersion = '4.12'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'ee.bcs.valiit'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context-support:${springVersion}",
            "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:${springDataVersion}",
            "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${springVersion}",
            "org.springframework:spring-web:${springVersion}",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jacksonVersion}",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:${jacksonVersion}",
            "org.springframework:spring-context-support:${springVersion}",
            "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:${hibernateVersion}",
            "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:${hibernateJpaVersion}",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jacksonVersion}"
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-dependencies', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    runtime "org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresqlVersion}"
    testCompile "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
}
```

I have no idea what could be wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: can you update your question with Application class and build.gradle?

Comment: @PallavKabra sure :)

Comment: Since you're using spring boot annotations you really should scrap the XML config. Add `@Repository` to your repository interface and you may need `@EnableJpaRepositories` on your application class.